# How can I output full HTML of jQuery object, including the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to build up some HTML, for which I would like to later get the HTML string.  One of the things I am adding is some background data(), which I believe translates to the data-* attributes of the element.  Here is an example:

```
var test = $("<div></div>");
test.data("foo", "bar");
var test2 = $("<div></div>");
test.text("blah");
test2.append(test);
console.log(test2.html());
```

Unfortunately, when I output the HTML to the log, I get this:

```
<div>blah</div>
```

but not the "foo" data.  Is there an API call that will output the HTML for a jQuery object, including any data that has been set in it?

Comment: The data is a property set on the DOM object and not an attribute of the html. [Some good reading here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731)

Comment: `jQuery#outerHTML()`

Comment: @PitaJ that will not get any of the DOM properties that have been set...

Comment: He'll have to convert the jQuery data to data attributes first, then

Comment: If you're trying to set the attr on the html you should try `selector.attr('key, 'value')`

Comment: Or just not use jQuery's data function in the first place. `test.attr("data-foo", "bar");` isn't much longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data will set a value on the object you have there - `test` in your example , not the rendered html. What I believe you are looking for is `attr`

See what I mean here -

```
var test = $("<div></div>");
test.attr("foo", "foo");
test.attr("bar", "bar");
var test2 = $("<div></div>");
test.text("blah");
test2.append(test);
console.log(test2.html());
```

In the console - this now reads like `<div foo="foo" bar="bar">blah</div>`;. Here it is in fiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/3849/

You can change the first or second arguments to whatever you want. The first argument is the name, and the second argument is the value, so if you did :

```
test.attr('data-test', 'my value!');
```

You'd end up with

```
<div data-test="my value!">
```

You can read more about jquery `attr` here - http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you desire:

```
var test = $("<div></div>");
test.attr("data-foo", "bar");
var test2 = $("<div></div>");
test.text("blah");
test2.append(test);
console.log(test2[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the .data() method doesn't create an actual data-info attribute.
to set an attr use .attr()

```js
var test = $("<div></div>");
    test.attr('data-foo', 'bar');
    var test2 = $("<div></div>");
    test.text("blah");
    test2.append(test);
    console.log(test2.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```